# JQuery animate and CSS transition not coordinating

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-transitions, timing

I'm trying to accomplish a simple transition.  I want the "Welcome" text to move downward and scale in size at the same time.

It seems when I run this code, the "Welcome" text moves down slightly, stops, the text size increases to the amount specified in js, THEN it continues moving to the spot I specified in js.

What am I doing wrong and how do I get them to transition at the same time?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzgwNx

Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#welcome").animate({top: "300px"}, 1500 );
  $("#welcome").css({fontSize: "70px", transition: "1.5s"});
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

p {
  font-size: 5em;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 153px;
}

nav {
  background: transparent;
  height: 3vw;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  text-align: right;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 17;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  /*float: right;*/
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  transition: 0.25s;
}

nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

header {
  background: url(main.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
}

#welcome {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1 id="welcome">Welcome</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: CSS3 supports all this with frames rates that jQuery would never be able to handle.  Why are you using jQuery for this?

Comment: This happens because when you set `transition` inline in the JS, it defaults to `all`. Meaning that besides getting animated, the change of `top` also get transitioned. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WmVWgZ) I've changed the JS to set `transitionDuration`, while specifying in the style to only transition `font-size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   You can achieve it using keyframe css.
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/dpes/pen/VNLePX/).